# Why does QGIS 1.8.0 crash when I try to set up CRS on Win XP?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, coordinate-system

I have a problem with my qgis 1.8.0. When I click on any button that set CRS or try to set the coordinates on the fly, qgis crash.  I try to uninstall the program and re-install it again using standalone.exe and the osgeo4w-setup installer but the problem persist.
My OS is windows XP ice.

I hope to not have to format PC!

Comment: Sounds like the problem described here: http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/clicking-Project-properties-crashes-qgis-td4983177.html.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by deleting the .qgis folder and removing the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS.