# Looking for log file after QGIS startup crash

Tags: qgis, windows-7, log

I have a problem with QGIS 1.8 with OSGEO4W installer (windows 7 - 64 bit).
QGIS crash on startup, it shows the splash screen and then nothing.
I have updated from an old 1.7.4 QGIS version.
I have done the same procedure in a portable computer and it works fine.
The problem is only in the workstation.

Is there a log file to view what the problem is?

Comment: try unistall and reinstall. is your workstation old? perhaps it is not 64 bit or windows 7.

Comment: I have tried to uninstall and reinstall QGIS and then OSGEO4W completely, but the problem doesn't solve. My workstation is relatively new, 64 bit windows 7 service pack 1, I have just controlled in control panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today i stumbled on the same problem (Win 7 64-bit, QGis 1.8.0). In search of a solution i disabled all plugins (in the registry), deleted the .qgis folder, Qgis registry entries and reinstalled, but nothing helped. However, i had QGis working just fine about a week or two ago. My QGis was crashing when the splash screen displayed "Starting python" (or something similar) and i remembered that i recently upgraded from Python 2.7.2 to 2.7.4.

So, i reinstalled python 2.7.2, changed environment variables to point to python 2.7.2 and now my QGis works again. Check your python version, you might have the same problem.

Comment: Great, the problem was this, thank you very much. I have disinstalled all version of python and purged every reference in register, and now QGis start again. Now I need only to reinstall Python 2.7.2. Thank again.

Comment: @AlessandroBattistini : 
I'm glad you got things sorted out :) I would be grateful if you marked my answer as the accepted solution, if it helped you out :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to delete your .qgis folder. Usually under c:\windows\users\. See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/57335/3438

Comment: I have deleted .qgis folder in C:\Users\Alessandro. I have also tried to remove the registry key KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS. When I launch QGIS, it re-create the folder and the key but doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I just solved the issue with Nathan W (a real Guru!). I had a file called path.txt in my c:\ and this caused QGIS-Dev build to fail (Lisboa worked fine though).

Just rename the file (c:\path.txt) if it exists. Also install OSGEO4W in admin.

See [QGIS Dev install issues](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63629/qgis-dev-install-issues) for details.